# Texture paint only painting on one image

Tags: texturing, image, texture-painting

I am trying to make an object switch textures through a mix shader and when I try to draw on the other texture it only paints on the first texture.

This is the texture I want to draw on: [image]

But instead it paints on this texture: [image]

Comment: in the N panel > Tool > Texture Slots, make sure you've selected the image you want to paint on

Comment: It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *N* panel > *Tool > Texture Slots*, make sure you've selected the image you want to paint on.